# Database design slightly different object

Tags: mysql, database-design

What is the best way to design a db with object types that share some columns but also have some of there own ?

Have 1 table for the shared data and let each type has its own table

> [objects]   o_id | o_name | object_type
>
> [object_type_1]  o_t_id | o_id | option1 | option 2
>
> [object_type_2]  o_t_id | o_id | option3 | option 4

OR
have all the columns in 1 table and have a lot of NULL's

> [objects]   o_id | o_name | object_type | option1 | option 2 | option3
>   | option 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem. A single best solution does not exist. You'll have to weigh the pros and cons of each always depending on your model.

Have a look at your options:

- http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html
- http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html
- http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html

A different approach, for your extra properties, is EAV. This has some serious benefits but also some tremendous drawbacks, so becareful before thinking that it is the "silver bullet":

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the purpose of the tables. Are you creating fact tables? Interaction tables? varied lookup tables?

Here's a link to a simple tutorial on `database normalization`:

http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/

Could you tell us more about the table structures? And what is the forecast on the growth of these tables?

There's a chance, depending on your purpose, that approach 1 will be of use and in another, maybe approach 2 will be of use..

Comment: you could compare it with a sort of facebook. the object types are articles, videos, discounts, etc